# How do I avoid using a constant for filename size?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, posix

It seems like standard programming practice and the POSIX standard are at odds with each other. I'm working with a program and I noticed that I see a lot of stuff like:

```
char buf[NAME_MAX + 1]
```

And I'm also seeing that a lot of operating systems don't define `NAME_MAX` and say that that they technically don't have to according to POSIX because you're supposed to use pathconf to get the value it's configured to at runtime rather than hard-coding it as a constant anyway.

The problem is that the compiler won't let me use pathconf this way with arrays. Even if I try storing the result of pathconf in a const int, it still throws a fit and says it has to be a constant. So it looks like in order to actually use pathconf, I would have to avoid using an array of chars for the buffer here because that apparently isn't good enough. So I'm caught between a rock and a hard place, because the C++ standard seemingly won't allow me to do what POSIX says I must do, that is determine the size of a character buffer for a filename at runtime rather than compile time.

The only information I've been able to find on this suggests that I would need to replace the array with a vector, but it's not clear how I would do it. When I test using a simple program, I can get this to work:

```
std::vector<char> buf((pathconf("/", _PC_NAME_MAX) + 1));
```

And then I can figure out the size by calling `buf.size()` or something. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach at all. Does anyone have any experience with trying to get a program to stop depending on constants like `NAME_MAX` or `MAXNAMLEN` being defined in the system headers and getting the implementation to use pathconf at runtime instead?

Comment: `std::string` is useful.

Comment: I am not familiar with POSIX or pathconf, but generally, If I am unable to determine the amount of memory I need at compile-time, I use dynamic memory allocation (e.g. malloc or new) to allocate memory for my char array. That way, you don't have to specify a constant.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Halfway measures do tend to result in conflicts of some sort.

```
const usigned NAME_MAX = /* get the value at runtime */;
char buf[NAME_MAX + 1];
```

The second line declares a C-style array (presumably) intended to hold a C-style string. In C, this is fine. In C++, there is an issue because the value of `NAME_MAX` is not known at compile time. That's why I called this a halfway measure—there is a mix of C-style code and C++ compiling. (Some compilers will allow this in C++. Apparently yours does not.)

The C++ approach would use C++-style strings, as in:

```
std::string buf;
```

That's it. The size does not need to be specified since memory will be allocated as needed, provided you avoid C-style interfaces. Use streaming (`>>`) when reasonable. If the buffer is being filled by user or file input, this should be all you need.

---

If you need to use C-style strings (perhaps this buffer is being filled by a system call written for C?), there are a few options for allocating the needed space. The simplest is probably a vector, much like you were thinking.

```
std::vector<char> buf{NAME_MAX + 1};
system_call(buf.data()); // Send a char* to the system call.
```

Alternatively, you could use a C++-style string, which could make manipulating the data more convenient.

```
std::string buf{NAME_MAX + 1, '\0'};
system_call(buf.data()); // Send a char* to the system call.
```

There is also a smart pointer option, but the `vector` approach might play nicer with existing code written for a C-style array.